# HashTable in C, trouble appending nodes, getting incompatible pointer type error

Tags: c, pointers, hash, hashtable

```
typedef struct HashNode{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
node *addThisNode = malloc(sizeof(node)); 
        addThisNode->data = scannedInt;
        addThisNode->next = NULL;
node **hashTable = malloc(10000*sizeof(node));
    for (int i =0 ; i < 10000; i ++){
        hashTable[i] = NULL;
    }

void append(node **hashTable, node *addThisNode, int hashedValue){
    node *ptr = hashTable[hashedValue];
    while (ptr->next != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = addThisNode;
}
```

The following is a hash table in C. I defined the table to be an array of pointers to nodes. In the case of a collision, I implemented node chaining via the append function. Now, when I go to increment the pointer in the append function, I am getting an "assignment from incompatible pointer type" error, and the same error when I try to assign ptr->next to the addThisNode. My understanding now is that by doing
"ptr->next = addThisNode" , they are the same type, Node, and should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: `node **hashTable = malloc(10000*sizeof *hashTable);` (your allocation was actually too large) And for an empty slot `ptr->next = addThisNode;` will dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: regarding; `typedef struct HashNode{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;`  This does not compile because the compiler doesn't know what a `struct node` is.

Comment: OT: regarding: `node *addThisNode = malloc(sizeof(node));`  (and other calls to `malloc()`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "my error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct xxx {
    int data;
    struct xxx *next;
        };

typedef struct xxx node;

node **hashTable = malloc(10000*sizeof * hashTable);
    for (int i =0 ; i < 10000; i ++){
        hashTable[i] = NULL;
    }

void append(node **hashTable, node *addThisNode, int hashedValue){
    node **pp ; 

    for(pp = &hashTable[hashedValue]; *pp; pp = &(*pp)->next) {;}
    *pp = addThisNode;
}
```

---

O, and BTW: you don't need the typedef. I only causes confusion.

Comment: I am still getting and error incrementing the pp. It says,  ptr = &(*ptr)->next) yields an assignment from incompatible pointer type

Comment: remove or repair the silly typedef: `typedef struct HashNode{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;`

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that `struct node` and `struct HashNode` are different types.

The `node` typedef name is an alias for `struct HashNode` and has nothing to do with `struct node`.

```
typedef struct HashNode {
  int data;
  struct node *next; // this should be struct HashNode
} node;
```

I suggest using `struct node` instead of `struct HashNode`, or *vice versa*: use the same identifier for the struct tag and for the typedef name:

```
typedef struct HashNode {
  int data;
  struct HashNode *next; // this should be struct HashNode
} HashNode;
```

If `struct HashNode` and `HashNode` are the same via `typedef`, and no identifier other than `HashNode` is introduced, you are less likely to run into this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct HashNode{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

In this construction, `node` is a type (but only **after** the `typedef` statement), and is equivalent to say `struct HashNode`.  What is not a type is to say `struct node`, which is an incomplete structure type, and a pointer to it will generate the error you post in the question title if you try to dereference it (the compiler doesn't know, because you have not yet defined the internal structure of `struct node` type)

Of course, the types `struct node` and `node` have nothing in common (the first is a complete type, the second is an incomplete, not yet defined type) and this is the reason that a pointer to one is not compatible with a pointer to the other type.

You could have said:

```
typedef struct HashNode{
    int data;
    struct HashNode *next;
} node;
```

or

```
/* forward reference, struct HashNode is not yet complete,
 *  but the compiler knows already that node is a type. */
typedef struct HashNode node;

struct HashNode{
    int data;
    node *next;
};  /* now struct HashNode type is complete */
```

In this last second way, the incomplete definition is used to know that the type `node` is defined as some incomplete structure, in order to be able to use it later in the `node *next;` declaration.  Had we not done it first, the `node *next;` definition would have given an error, as the type `node` had not yet been defined.

In C, the names used for `struct`, union`,` enum`types belong to a different namespace than the named types themselves, so`struct foo`is not the same as`foo`(this is not true in C++, where for each`struct foo`you are creating a`class`with all members`public`, probably your mistake comes from using a c++ compiler)